# Deprecate Typedef

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I have a few TypeDefs that I want to deprecate. I am doing this to retain backward compatibility with code that already exists. Is there an elegant (or maybe not so elegant) solution to this? I would like it to be platform independent but if there is a Visual Studio only solution, that will do as well.

Comment: There is no portable solution.  @Nawaz gave the Microsoft extension.  The gcc equivalent is `typedef int myint __attribute__((deprecated));`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this question is 10 years old, but for anyone still asking this question, this syntax has been supported [since C++14](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/deprecated):

```
[[deprecated("reason")]] typedef int type;
```

Answer (score 11):

In MSVC++, you can deprecate `typedef` like this:

```
typedef __declspec(deprecated) int myint;
```

The MSVC++ compiler will generate warning that `myint`is deprecated!

And if you want the compiler to generate a specific message when compiling a deprecated typedef, then do this:

```
typedef __declspec(deprecated("myint is deprecated, so most likely in the next version this myint will be missing")) int myint;
```

Comment: do what? i think you missed the last part :))

Comment: @KitsuneYMG: Yes. That was a typo. Thanks!

Comment: MSVC also has `#pragma deprecated`, which works for macros too.

Answer (score 4):

If one-off easy code changes are allowed you could just move the typedef into a `deprecated` namespace requiring the use of `using namespace deprecated` at the points that use the typedef.

If that's not an option it *might* be possible to concoct a template that, when instantiated, would generate a warning, but I don't know how to generate such a warning offhand:

```
template <class T>
class TypedefHolder;

template <>
class TypedefHolder<int>
{
    typedef int WhateverType;
    // Something that induces a compile warning.
};
```

so instead of:

```
typedef int WhateverType;
```

it becomes:

```
typedef TypedefHolder<int>::WhateverType WhateverType;
```

Comment: I think this is a very good solution if I could generate compiler warnings. Anybody have any thoughts on custom warnings?